# How to ensure that at least one of A and B sign appears in the regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
s_l = ["春天年初, ...","1999年", "很多年以前"]
for front_part in s_l:
    idx_year = re.search(r'[\d]*[年]{1}[初末底前]{0,1}',front_part).end() \
    if re.search(r'[\d]*[年]{1}[初末底前]{0,1}',front_part) else 0
    print(idx_year)
```

I want to search the idx of sub-string that has `年`， and at the same time, there must be digits(sign A) before `年` **or** `[初末底前]`(sign B) behind "年", for example,in s_l, it should return `4,5,0`

One idea to divide the regex, like

```
re.search(r'[\d]+[年]{1}',front_part) or re.search(r'[年]{1}[初末底前]{0,1}',front_part)
```

but it is too complex, other one is using `(?=...)` but I haven't got the idea and how to use it,any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think that using separate regexes is "too complex". You will probably find it easier to understand - and maintain - than the all-in-one approach.

Comment: Do not use `{1}` in any regex, it is simply redundant and does not do anything. `{0,1}` can always be written as a short `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind assertion to match an occurrence of `年` that's preceded by a digit. Use an alternation pattern to match one that's followed by `[初末底前]`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)年|年[初末底前]')
print([match.end() if match else 0 for match in map(pattern.search, s_l)])
```

This outputs:

```
[4, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
lst = ["春天年初, ...","1999年", "很多年以前"]
pattern = re.compile("(.*\d|初末底前)年.*")
for i, s in enumerate(lst):
  patterns = list(pattern.finditer(s))
  if patterns != []:
    print(list(map(lambda item:(i, item.span()), patterns)))
```

The output would be something like `[(1, (0, 5))]`. Here the first part of every element of this list would be the index of the string from the list `lst` which matches the conditions. The second part would be the index of the occurence of those conditions in the list item.